# Can I cache audio on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio

My app allows users to upload recordings of their voice taken via the iPhone's build-in microphone.  It then uploads this to the server. Other users can play other people's audio uploads however each time a user would like to replay the same audio file it has to retrieve it again from the server.  Is there a way for it to be cached on the iPhone?

Also, wondering whether there's a way to compress the audio before sending it to the server?

Thanks,

Stuart

Answer (score 1):

You can:

A: write the sound to Caches folder. Since it is probably created from NSData it is very easy.

B: use NSCache (avilable since iOS 4.0). It is very similar to the dictionary, but it behaves  in the way, that when it is not enough free memory it deletes some of the records.